# Show mention button on ckeditor's toolbar

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I've added Mention feature to my ckeditor:

```
this.ckEditorConfig['mention'] = {
     feeds: [
            {
                  marker: '#',
                  feed: this.getTagFeedItems.bind(this),
                  itemRenderer: this.tagFeedItemRenderer.bind(this)
            }
     ]
};
```

It works as expected but is it possible to add "#" button on my toolbar? This button is expected to add # sign to the text field and thereby trigger the Mention feature.

My ckeditor configs:

```
{
    placeholder: 'Type a new message',
    toolbarLocation: 'bottom',
    toolbar: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'highlight', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'fontSize', 'fontColor'],
    removePlugins: ['ListStyle'],
    extraPlugins: [MentionCustomization],
    ...
}
```